# How do I show this sequence of functions is uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

EDIT:  I think I might have my answer now:  the maximums $M_n$ are increasing with each subsequent.  So the limit of $M_n$, $\large \frac{1}{e}$, is indeed the uniform bound, I believe.

The sequence is $f_n(x) = nx(1-x)^n$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

I found that the maximizer is $x_n$ = $ \frac {1}{n+1}$, by solving for $f_n'(x)=0$, and noting that the second derivative $f_n''(x)$ is negative at the critical point $\frac {1}{n+1}$.

Then evaluating the original sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ at $x_n$ gives the maximum

$$M_n = (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}})^{n+1}  $$

Now, the limit of $x_n$ = $0$ and the limit of $M_n$ = $\large \frac{1}{e}$

The part of the question that I am stuck on is:

**Show that in the interval $0\le x \le 1$ the functions $f_n(x)$ are uniformly bounded.  Does  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)dx$$**

The solution gives an answer that I'm concerned may not be correct.  It says that "since $\large \frac{1}{e}$ is the maximum on [0,1], then it uniformly bounds $f_n(x)$.

Is this correct?  I think that the maximum that I found above is of course a maximum over [0,1], but it *depends* on n.  So for every n *fixed*, $f_n(x)$ has a maximum $M_n$ over [0,1].  I don't see why the limit of $M_n$ = $\frac {1}{e}$ would be a max for *all n*, and hence uniformly bounding the sequence of functions.

Also, I guess answering the above question will allow me to answer the question of the equality above, and justifying taking the limit inside of the integral.  I need to use Dominated Convergence Theorem and show that $f_n(x)$ is bounded (for all n) by an integrable function.  I know that I cannot use the weaker uniform convergence claim to justify moving the limit inside, since the convergence is not uniform.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)=e^{-1}, $$
however $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. Therefore $f_n$ does not converge uniformly, as you correctly concluded. However, for each $n$ we have $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)= \left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$, and $\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ increases monotonically to $e^{-1}$. Therefore $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n\leqslant e^{-1}$ and
$$\int_0^1 e^{-1}\ \mathsf dx = e^{-1}<\infty, $$
so by dominated convergence it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx = 0. $$

Comment: Hi @Math1000, thanks so much for this very pretty solution.  Is that a standard technique to rewrite the max as you did?  With the way I derived it, it was very hard to see whether it's increasing, decreasing, or oscillates.  For example, I was thinking that the denominator "goes up to e", then 1/denominator "goes *down* to 1/e.  So, I couldn't conclude that 1/e was a legitimate uniform bound for all n.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Since $1-\frac1{n+1}<1$ and $x\mapsto\log x$ is monotonically increasing, we have $\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=(n+1)\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)$ and so $\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ is increasing.

Comment: Ok, got it -- cool example.  Thanks so much @Math1000 :-)

Comment: Hi @Math1000, I also just wanted to point this out, and was wondering whether you could confirm:  this example shows that although uniform convergence of continuous functions gives a limit function that is again continuous, just because continuous functions converge to a limit function that is again continuous does *not* mean the  convergence had to uniform - one still has to check this, as in this problem.  However, the contrapositive is correct:  continuous functions converging to a limit that is *not* continuous implies that the convergence could not have been uniform.  Is this ok? Thanks,

Comment: That is correct. The counterexample I keep in mind is $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$.